# Evaluating $\sin\left(\arccos\frac12+\arccos\frac{7}{25}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Evaluate $$\sin\left(\arccos\frac12+\arccos\frac{7}{25}\right)$$

I know that $\arccos\frac12$ is $60^\circ$. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You can draw a triangle and use your sum properties.

Comment: How can you do that ?

Comment: You know the adjacent leg, the hypotenuse. Hint, it's a pythagorean triplet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sin\left(\arccos\frac12+\arccos\frac{7}{25}\right)=$$

$$\sin(x+y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$$

Where $$x=\arccos\frac12$$ and $$y=  \arccos\frac{7}{25}$$

Note that $$ \cos x =\frac {1}{2}$$ and $$ \cos y =\frac {7}{25}$$

We can find $$ \sin x= {\sqrt 3}/2 $$ and $$\sin y = 24/{25}$$

upon substitution we get $$\sin\left(\arccos\frac12+\arccos\frac{7}{25}\right)=$$

$$        {7\sqrt 3}/50 +24/{50} = \frac { 7\sqrt 3 + 24}{50}    $$

Comment: Everything makes sense until your final answer.  Check the last line.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, I have  edited my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

let 
$$
\cos \alpha= \frac{1}{2} \qquad \cos \beta= \frac{7}{25}
$$

so yo u have to evaluate  $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$.

Use the addition formula and, given $\cos \beta=\frac{7}{25}$  find $\sin \beta=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 \beta}$